# loading message with jquery and calling id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I made a small shoutbox for my site and I am loading the page with jquery and storing all my data in a database like usual. anyways, when a user wants to edit a post they double click on it and they can edit their post. I am using the following code to show the editor and let them do whatever they need to with it. sadly something isn't working and that something is:

**i cant include my tag `id` in the `url:` on my ajax call**

Here's is a look at the code

```
<? php
    public function make_editable($shout, $id) {
        $string = "<span ondblclick=\"javascript: edit_shout('".$id."'); return false;\">".$shout."</span>";
        return $string;
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function edit_shout($id) {
         $("#panel_edit_shout").slideDown();
         $('#update').val($id);
         $('#delete').val($id);
         $.ajax({
             url : "/chat?loadModule=3&id={$id}",
             dataType: "text",
             success : function (data) {
                 $("#updateshoutmessage").val(data);
             }
         });
   }
</script>
```

If i replace the {$id} with say, 1 for example, then it works correctly and loads the text of shout id 1 into the field like its supposed to, but if I try and load dynamically using $id, it just gets an error because the $id is coming up as blank... Thanks for your help :).

Comment: umm what is $id? you need to show us where that gets set

Comment: Seems that, being in JS, you expect _PHP variable_ `$ id` to be recognized! Please show more of your code (HTML + JS + PHP).

Comment: if $id is a number why are you creating it as a jquery object? try something like this: "/chat?loadModule=3&id="+id   where id = a number value

Comment: i have updated the code for you, i mentioned jquery did i not? lol. will try `url : "/chat?loadModule=3&id=" + $id,` and see thanks

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... if the variable is in javascript you can do:

```
url : "/chat?loadModule=3&id=" + $id,
```

If it is php then you have to do

```
url : "/chat?loadModule=3&id=<?=$id?>",
```

But like the other guys said, without more code we can't help much.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy fix thanks to @Dranes for his help. Simply needed to add +

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function edit_shout($id) {
         $("#panel_edit_shout").slideDown();
         $('#update').val($id);
         $('#delete').val($id);
         $.ajax({
             url : "/chat?loadModule=3&id=" + $id,
             dataType: "text",
             success : function (data) {
                 $("#updateshoutmessage").val(data);
             }
         });
   }
</script>
```